# Trying to determine why checking in files in one project, would trigger a build in another unrelated project

Tags: tfs, tfvc

One of my colleagues has made some changes to a project, named "DB Conversion". There are 2 TFS builds associated with the PharmacyWarehouse project. Here's a picture so you can see what I'm talking about.

[image]

A previous TFS Administrator set this configuration up. I inherited it when he left. As you can see PharmacyWarehouse is just a folder. But the 2 builds have a Visual Studio Build step which only looks at the PharmacyWarehouse.sln file in the PharmacyWarehouse folder. I've looked at that .sln file, it only references packages, PharmacyWarehouse and UnitTests folders. I've looked at the .csproj files, they only reference those folders/VS projects.

I've looked at the DBConversion.sln and DBConversion.csproj files in the Projects | "DB Conversion" folder. It only references that folder/VS project. The files my colleague was editing are in the Projects | "DB Conversion" | Models folder.

Why would checking in changes in Projects | "DB Conversion" | Models folder cause the TFS trigger watching the PharmacyWarehouse.sln to fire? Is it because their folders and not TFS Projects?

We're working with TFS 2015

Comment: Could you share the build definition here? Such as CI configuration and build path. If you push code in the project DB Conversion, it will build the project DB Conversion and PharmacyWarehouse, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the screenshot, you are using TFVC version control.

1. Open build definition, click the tab **Trigger** and check the trigger field **Path specification** and ensure the path is `$/Pharmacy Warehouse /DB Conversion`
2. Open build definition, click the tab **Get sources** and check the field **Workspace mappings**, ensure the path is `$/Pharmacy Warehouse /DB Conversion`.

After configuration, if we push the changes to the folder or project DB Conversion, it will trigger this build and only build DB Conversion.

Comment: That was it. It was looking at the primary Pharmacy Warehouse TFS Team Project. Any change there was causing it to build. Thank you!